# how to run an android wear app in virtual devices?

Tags: wear-os

how to run an android wear app in virtual devices? i want to learn android wear develop, but i do not have a watch, so i want to use a virtual devices.
i set up a virtual devices in eclipse, 4.4.2W, when i run the app, the virtual device do not occur in the select devices list

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="20"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity android:name="com.example.helloword.MyActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Android-SDK get the complete set of things installed for 4.4.2W, and launch an AVD with Android Wear Round...you will be good to go :)